# Path to images in Symfony with siphoc/PdfBundle

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, bundle

I am developing a management portal with Symfony2 and have the need to **create reports in PDF** (*to download or watch online*) and looking for some bundle to help me do this I found [siphoc/PdfBundle](https://github.com/siphoc/PdfBundle), I'm **running** and I generate reports to from a view, **correctly**.

Now I have the **need to put an image** in the header of sight, I do so with the `asset` function and referencing the image, as you would in any other view, but the **image is not displayed in the generated PDF**.

I have been looking for information about how to insert an image in the view to generate a PDF by then [siphoc/PdfBundle](https://github.com/siphoc/PdfBundle) but I have **not found anything** about it.

Does anyone have idea how to insert an image in the PDF file?

**Greetings and thank you very much.**

---

#### Edit: More info

It has to do with relative paths, with the type `http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg` the images appear correctly in the generated PDF .